# Silverlight 4.0 Copy Paste data into AutoComplete Box

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, autocomplete

I am using a Autocomplete textbox for "like" search text from Database using KeyDown Event.
One of the scenario is COPY-PASTE textname to Autocompletebox where data is already available in Database.

I was unable to complete this scenario because when i am trying to paste the text, "Ctrl" is getting fired instead of "Ctrl+V" from kepboard.

Here is the code for your reviews

```
string a = autoCompleteBox2.Text + e.Key.ToString().ToLower();

if (FirstKey.Equals("ctrl") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Key.ToString()))
{
    a = autoCompleteBox2.Text;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && a.Length > 0 && !CurrentKey.Equals("ctrl"))
{
    pvm.SearchDrug(4, a);
}
FirstKey = e.Key.ToString().ToLower();
```

this event is taking "Ctrl" instead of "Ctrl+ V".

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the KeyDown event to trigger search in an AutoCompleteBox. Please refer to the incredibly helpful post "[AutoCompleteBox - The Missing Guide](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/autocompletebox-missing-guide/)" by Jeff Wilcox.

The event you want is Populating, which will fire regardless of whether the text is typed or pasted and respects the delayed reaction, minimum length, etc.